# How to collect properties of a list to another list in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, list

please advice which is the best way to fill a class property in the list with  properties of list of another class in C#.

I have

```
class Source 
{
   public object A {get; set;}
   public object B {get; set;}
   public object C {get; set;}
}

class Destination
{
   public object A {get; set;}
   public object B {get; set;} // (A,B) is a unique key
   public List<object> Cs {get; set;}
   public object D {get; set;} 
}
```

then I have

```
List <Destination> destinations; // Cs = null
List <Source> sources; //may have zero, one or more than one Cs for (A,B)
```

How can I fill Cs of Destinations (or another class) with C of Sources? Is it possible to use LINQ here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is the most misunderstood question I have ever seen....:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group sources by A and B (your unique key), and then select C from all items in group:

```
var destinations = from s in sources
                   group s by new { s.A, s.B } into g
                   select new Destination()
                   {
                       A = g.Key.A,
                       B = g.Key.B,
                       Cs = g.Select(x => x.C).ToList()
                   };
```

UPDATE if you need to update existing destinations

```
foreach(var d in destinations)
   d.Cs = sources.Where(s => s.A == d.A && s.B && d.B).ToList();
```

OR (I believe this will be faster)

```
var lookup = sources.ToLookup(s => new { s.A, s.B }, s => s.C);
foreach (var d in destinations)            
     d.Cs = lookup[new { d.A, d.B }].ToList();
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/8Xl3eA#view_edit_box)

Comment: I assume OP wants update its `Destenations` collection with data from `Sources`. Your query gives new collection.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan in this case he should go with something like Choung Le suggested

Comment: The `Cuong Le` solution also copies `Destinations` collection but is more correct.

Comment: More consistent with the requirements of OP.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan you think usage of Select to modify sequence is consistent?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I mean that select operator not supposed to have side effects like modifying sequence. And what did you mean by more consistent?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Thanks! I appreciate your participation and comments!

Comment: @lazyberezovsky it is possible to change (add ) items to list using linq ?(not creating new one)...right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir last two samples show how to change existing items. If you want to add new items, then use `list.AddRange(queryResult)`

Answer (score 3):

LINQ to the rescue:

```
sources = destinations.SelectMany(d => d.Cs);
```

You might want

```
sources = destinations.SelectMany(d => 
    d.Cs.Select(c => new Source { A = d.A, B = d.B, C = c })
);
```

Comment: Looks like he wants destinations from sources

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure I was clear enough destinations is an existing list Cs of destinations just not filled. Does it change anything?

Comment: @Dmitry You can't change collection using LINQ.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Whaty do you mean by that ? I can't change collection in Linq ? I think lazyberezovsky done it...no ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I mean not a good practice when linq has side effect like collection modification.